# autogen.sh not found for webkit

Tags: scripts, configuration, webkit

I'm trying to install Webkit in ubuntu 12.04 following this instructions:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WebKit

When I get to this instruction:

```
./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr
```

I got an error message:

```
bash: ./autogen.sh: file or directory not found
```

I thought the script autogen.sh should be in the directory I had downloaded, but it is not there. So I've tried to download it from here:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/buildconf/files/latest/download

And put it in the directory in which I'm working (following the instructions in :~/src/WebKit$). But it doesn't work either.

```
~/src/WebKit$ ./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr
Unknown option: --prefix=/usr

Usage: ./autogen.sh [-h|--help] [-v|--verbose] [-q|--quiet] [-d|--download] [--version]
--help      Help on autogen.sh usage
--verbose   Verbose progress output
--quiet     Quiet suppressed progress output
--download  Download the latest config.guess from gnulib
--version   Only perform GNU Build System version checks

Description: This script will validate that minimum versions of the

GNU Build System tools are installed and then run autoreconf for you.
Should autoreconf fail, manual preparation steps will be run
potentially accounting for several common preparation issues.  The
AUTORECONF, AUTOCONF, AUTOMAKE, LIBTOOLIZE, ACLOCAL, AUTOHEADER,
PROJECT, & CONFIGURE environment variables and corresponding _OPTIONS
variables (e.g. AUTORECONF_OPTIONS) may be used to override the
default automatic detection behavior.

autogen.sh build preparation script by Christopher Sean Morrison
  + config.guess download patch by Sebastian Pipping (2008-12-03)
revised 3-clause BSD-style license, copyright (c) 2005-2009
script version 20090301, ISO/IEC 9945 POSIX shell script
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to build WebKit from source using the SVN repo, all you have to do is to use the provided build scripts:

```
./Tools/gtk/install-dependencies 
./Tools/Scripts/build-webkit --gtk
```

By default, build-webkit places build products in WebKitBuild. The `WEBKIT_OUTPUTDIR` environment variable can be used to set a different build products location. If you have set up a custom build location, then build-webkit will place the build products there.

Note: I assume that you're building for a GTK target (you can choose Efl, WinCE or GTK)

Source: https://www.webkit.org/building/build.html